# C# Multipart Mime object

Tags: c#, mime, multipart

I am receiving file through url request  which has following contents.

```
--MSMboundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-ID:15870126
Object-ID:1
Content-Description: null

ÿØÿà JFIF  ` `  ÿÛ C        

 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛ C         

2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ  È " ÿÄ             
--MSMboundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-ID:15870126
Object-ID:2
Content-Description: null

ÿØÿà JFIF  ` `  ÿÛ C        

 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛ C         

2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ  È " ÿÄ             
ÿÄ µ   
--MSMboundary
```

How do I generate image and extract other contents using c#?

Thank you

Comment: Those are the bytes of the image. You just create a new bitmap from the bytes.

Comment: Any working example with help me a lot.

Comment: I can't help you because you have no code showing how you receive this string.

Comment: Finally I solve it using: http://code.crt.realtors.org/projects/librets/wiki/CsharpGetObject                       and installing https://libraries.io/nuget/librets-dotnet ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve it using: http://code.crt.realtors.org/projects/librets/wiki/CsharpGetObject                       and installing https://libraries.io/nuget/librets-dotnet ..