# Consuming multipart MIME object from SOAP message in WCF C#

Tags: c#, zip, mime, multipart, mtom

I have been having a lot of trouble getting this going in c# and googling has not worked out as i had hoped.

The problem is i am receiving this MTOM signal as a Stream object. It has 2 parts. The XML and a byte[] that is a ZIP file which i need to save to disk. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

I have tried MimeKit, MimeMessage, MimeEntity and a few other lesser known libraries and have had no luck interpreting my stream with these packages.

Here is the Stream when printed as a string:

```
----MIME_boundary
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Id: <start.xml>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  <soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xop = "http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"
  >
    <soap:Body>
      <COMPANYDOC>
        <COMPANYNET_INFO
          transactionId = "00486KZ"
        >
          <ATTACHMENTS>
            <ATTACHMENT>
              <xop:Include
                href = "cid:70049@COMPANY.com"
              />
            </ATTACHMENT>
          </ATTACHMENTS>
        </COMPANYNET_INFO>
      </COMPANYDOC>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
----MIME_boundary
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="COMPANYDOC.ZIP"
Content-Id: <70049@COMPANY.com>

PK
```

It all looks fine but i am unable to read it and unfortunately this service is older and cannot be changed.

```
var mpp = new MultipartParser(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
```

Gives me StartIndex cannot be less than zero

```
MimeKit.MimeEntity mime = MimeKit.MimeEntity.Load(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
```

It just sort of creates a new mimeEntity with content-type: text/xml and it doesn't have my MIME Header's split up.

[C# Multipart Mime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360682/c-sharp-multipart-mime-object)
This one is exactly what i need but his links don't work anymore

So my question is how can i go about parsing this multipart MTOM message in C# and at the end of the day get the ZIP attachment (which is all i really care about)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I have the same problem.  I need to write a custom encoder to write the MTOM attachment to the disk instead of storing it in a byte array.  The attachment will potentially be huge